# Solana Phantom Wallet - Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached

Tags: smartcontracts, solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-cli

I am working with a Solana project which works well on Linux when we deploy it with **devnet** or **localnet** but when I try to do the exact same steps for **mainnet** I got this error always.

> Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is
> reached.

I have waited for 48 hours may be the limit issue fixed but nothing happened. You can see I have SOL in my wallet and it confirms on CLI as well but when I try to Airdrop the SOL it gave me an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airdrops are not allowed on mainnet.  Otherwise, the network would be giving out free SOL, effectively eliminating any value on the token. To get mainnet SOL, you must purchase them, likely through an exchange.

Comment: Jon, you see I have 4.29 SOL in the phantom wallet. Does mainnet SOL are differnt? Also, if I skip the Airdrops command and hit 'anchor build' all fine but on 'anchor deploy' it says: "Error: Account MY_ACCOUNT_KEY has insufficient funds for spend (1.76319768 SOL) + fee (0.001275 SOL)
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }."

Comment: Also, I just did that: 

Solana balance MY_ACCOUNT_KEY

And it says 0.49949 SOL. Any idea why?

Comment: And storage on running "solana balance" now it says 0 SOL.

Comment: Your Phantom wallet may connect to any cluster (local, testnet, devnet, or mainnet usually). To deploy your program, you need to spend SOL. On non-mainnet clusters, you can get that SOL through an airdrop. You may want to do some more background reading on Solana clusters https://docs.solana.com/clusters and deploying programs https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program

Comment: Perfect all solved without a AirDrop